# Java AngularJS Spring MVC - $http.post 400 bad request syntactically incorrect when sending bean to controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing an application that would assume an admin that will create an Employee record with his/her particulars, and also assigning the newcomer with an existing "Team" as well as the skill sets corresponding to the roles/position that he/she has or require. Naturally That will have 4 different Objects to handle that. I've decided to use a bean to store the `Employee` Object, the `Team` Object, and the `Skills` and `Roles` Object.

The first bean will be to store the `Skills` and `Roles`, `RoleNSkills`. Each `Role`can require many `Skills` and an `Employee` can assume many `Roles`. Each `Employee` may only be assigned to one `Team` at a time. Hence the second bean will assume the list of `RoleNSkills` as well as the `employee` data and the `team` that he will be assigned to.

Note, `team` and `group` means the same thing in this context. We use `team` for front end purposes.

Error:

This are the object that Google Chrome returns me while I'm trying to figure out what is exactly which resource is causing me problems. I have previously added `employee` as a single resource and it worked so that will be ruled out.

JSON Formatter: http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html
Heres the full JSON that I managed to get it out from the object that I'm dealing with:

AngularJS making the post

Update: Still nothing. I suspect that it's because of the CreatedAt and UpdatedAt under the RoleNSkills being in milliseconds and I'm trying to post those to the controller and it completely rejects me. But I'm trying to find where those were defined but to no avail. If anyone is willing to help me search I can post any requested resource for you to look at.

Update2: Maybe, since inside my Database, it is defined in this manner `'2015-06-22 15:03:09'`, and when I issue a "get" to get all the skills and roles from the database, and it gives me in the format of milliseconds, I should do the same when I post?

Comment: I updated with error image

Comment: I stringified my object and it is an invalid JSON format according to an online formatter I used.

Comment: Added the JSON object in string

Comment: this error means that you send parameter that mismatch the type of your bean .. show us your beans `employee` `roleNSkills` `rawGroupToEmployee`

Comment: Done. And I suspect that, but I'm not entirely sure where

Comment: i think because `"dob": "2016-07-07T16:00:00.000Z",` is not correct date format, it must be a space like this `2016-07-07 16:00:00.000Z`

Comment: I just woke up. And seems legit. I'm using input=date so I'll try to format that and see if anything comes up.

Comment: to be sure try to delete the property with date from the bean and see if the request is okey

Comment: I'm looking around other guides, but I'm still not very sure how to convert it to just date, without the time and zone.

Comment: I tried using $scope.employe.dob = new Date().getTime(); but it deosnt really work. (the scope is my ng-model for that input field)

Comment: Could you ask other people to help take a look as well? Because apparently the person before me did the createdAt and updatedAt in milliseconds instead and I'm legit confused. He's not responding to me so I have to resort to here for now.

Comment: don't use input=date and try

Comment: use input type=text

Comment: I solved it. It was a stupid mistake. Thanks for your time though..

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is related to incorrect json being sent to the controller, most likely this would be fixed by using `JSON.stringify(paramEmployee)` which serializes a Javascript object into a string.

Comment: I tried that and tried to console.log(JSON.stringify(paramEmployee)) and it failed. That hinted me that the object may not be a valid JSON but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: just tried directly sending the stringified object to my controller and it didn't work.

Comment: Same thing, apparently

Comment: The console.log worked, it stringified it, but apparently it still can't send it to my controller, though.

Comment: Ok than, In your bean class do you have a default constructor?!

Comment: No, as you can see in the screenshot. But is that necessary?

Comment: In my case the problem was solved by adding constructors.